# rails 3 ruby 2 conditional validations not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, conditional-statements, ruby-2.0

I want to validate the note field only if the user_id field is blank?

I tried without a lambda:

```
   validates_presence_of :note, :unless => user_id?
```

I tried through a method:

```
   validates_presence_of :note, :unless => user_is_present?
   def user_is_present?
      self.user_id.present?
   end
```

I tried a lambda:

```
  validates_presence_of :note, :unless => lambda { self.user_id.present? }
```

I tried a Proc

```
  validates_presence_of :note, :unless => Proc.new { |x| x.user_id.present? }
```

All result in:

```
  "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 8 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id"
```

Trial & Error confirms is the nil value is the user_id...which is NOT validated and should not be failing.

1. first question is are there any errors in my attempts?
2. second question is how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
validates :note, presence: true, unless: 'user_id'
```

You don't need to define any methods...